# SVG Favicon Color Change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

I hope you all are having a great day / night.

So I was working on my personal portfolio and I'm using a svg as a favicon and I have a array of colors which is randomly chosen on refresh I want to change the favicon depending upon the color assigned to the variable is there a possible way I can do it?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="loaded">
<head>
  <link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icon/icon.svg" sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml" >
<head>
.....
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      // COLOR
      var colors = ["#00ffa2", "#660000", "#d70063", "#03e37f", "#a8a8c7", "#545435", "#413a97", "#c1c86b",
        "#c9f543", "#3207b8", "#ecdc29"
      ];
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
      var randcol = rand + 1
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

I wanna assign randcol to the favicon

Comment: You can't dynamically change the color of an SVG favicon through JS. If you wanted to do this you'd need to create multiple SVG files in each different colour, then update the favicon URL through JS.

Comment: Ohu I saw multiple articles, where they converted the svg into a image with some function and using css variables to get the color

Comment: You can use CSS within the SVG file itself, more info on how to do that [here](https://css-tricks.com/svg-favicons-and-all-the-fun-things-we-can-do-with-them/), but you can't use browser-based CSS to affect the favicon SVG file.

Answer (score -2):

For that I think you need to modify svg content so you should assign document favicon with javascript